# how set a preview in a surfaceview or something similar

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, preview

I need to put the pictures of the camera in a surfaceview (or everything else), any idea for the method to use?
for image view I put the image but I don't know how to do the preview(reverse problem)
I need to have the preview of the camera and after put photo inside.

```
Bitmap photo1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo1);
```

Comment: What's wrong with a FrameLayout that embeds both SurfaceView for camera and ImageView for bitmaps, and switching visibility of the children depending on the cirucmstance?

Comment: right...I try to use frame layout with surfaceView inside but I don't know how to save pictures in sd card(I don't know how to convert the data from surfaceView to a bitmap and save it, and how to create a preview of the pictures)

Comment: As **[fadden](http://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden)** explained elsewhere, you don't save pictures from SurfaceView. You should interact with the camera directly and save the pictures the way custom camera works. If you want to add decorations to these pictures, you apply them to bitmaps that will be saved.